# QTableView + QSqlTableModel - how to read id of selected row

Tags: qt, qt4, qtableview, qtsql

I'm using QTableView with QSqlTableModel. In my view I don't display the column containing record id. How can I acquire id of the selected row if its not displayed in any column ?

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Also you can retrieve id directly from QSqlQueryModel but I am not sure it's more convinient then proposed by soulSurfer.

Using `QModelIndex` for desired row:

```
QSqlQueryModel *model = tableView->model();
QSqlRecord record= model->record(desiredIndex->row());
QSqlField field = record.field(id_column_index);
int id = field.value().toInt();
```

Answer (score 5):

Hmmm...one way is to get the ID from the model and hide it in the view with

```
void QTableView::setColumnHidden (int column, bool hide)
```

then you basically get it, but hide it, and from here, you can get it easily with from the model directly by using the index emited from

```
void QAbstractItemView::activated ( const QModelIndex & index )
```

Signal.

Comment: This answer is standard and easy to use, i don't know why it's not Accepted answer!